# Javascript to Regex an input box

Tags: javascript

I am creating a sign in form for a phone number. My customers are only going to be local customers, but the oauth policy I am using requires the phone number to be entered with a +1 value.

Normal people are not going to enter that +1 so I want to create a JS regex to do it for me.

The issue im running into is that this JS works, however it is appending it AFTER the form submission. because if I run it again, it works fine.

For example

If I enter XXXXXXXXXX when I click submit on the form the console log shows +1XXXXXXXXXX
but the form is being submitted with XXXXXXXXXX

If i click submit again it works.

I dont really want the customer to see the +1 getting added to the input, as it could get confusing.

Any advice?

This is what I have so far.

Note: I have the pattern logic in there, but during testing I am not using it because I just want it to force the +1 right now to make sure its working. I can build logic afterward once its doing it consistantly.

```
document.forms.localAccountForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
  
  // Get the input element by its ID
  const inputElement = document.getElementById("signInName");
  
  // Get the current value of the input
  let inputValue = inputElement.value;
  
  // REGEX pattern to match the input value
  const pattern = /^(\+1)?(.*)$/;

    // Add "+1" in front of the input value
    inputValue = "+1" + inputValue;
    
    // Update the input value
    inputElement.value = inputValue;

  
  // Output the modified value (to test)
  console.log(inputElement.value);
  
  // Submit the form
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.forms.localAccountForm.submit();
  }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Where did you use `pattern`?

Comment: right now im not worrying about the pattern.. i removed that logic for now JUST to FORCE the +1 once i get that working right, I can build the logic.

Comment: If you're going to submit the form anyway, it's not clear why you bother to prevent the default action.

Comment: Try to remove the setTimeout.

Comment: I was hoping that it would stop the default inout and run the function before submission. I am not a JS master, but the article I read had it, and this made sense to me in my mind. Removing it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you checked the browser "Network" developer tool to see the actual form contents when it is posted?

Comment: @Pointy yes, st_type: RESPONSE
signInName: XXXXXXXXXX
password: Test

Comment: When resubmission happens it is appended just fine.

Comment: The browser doesn't need any time to update the `<input>` element value. My guess is that there's another submit handler submitting the form, or another form entirely.